# Groups Math Proof Help

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that the indicated set $G$ with the specified operation forms a group by showing that the four axioms in the definition of a group are satisfied.

$G = \mathbb Z_5$ under addition mod $5$.

I am confused and do not know how to begin. I am not really sure what $\mathbb Z_5$ under addition mod $5$ means.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, then you make a multiplication table. Addition mod $5$ means after you add $a$ and $b$, you take the remainder of dividing the result by $5$. $a+_5b=a+b\text{ mod }5$. Say $3+_54=3+4\text{ mod }5=7\text{ mod }5=2$.

Answer (score 0):

In General $G = \mathbb Z_n$ under addition mod $n$ forms a group.

$G = \mathbb Z_n$ means the set of elements under modulo n

```
  = { 0,1,...., n-1} 


  Now, to check if this is a group under addition modulo n, all you have to check is for the associativity property, the existence of an identity element in the above set and the existence of inverse for each of the elements in the above set.
```